# Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@escaping (_) -> _)' within combineLatest in RxSwift

Tags: swift, filter, rx-swift, combinelatest

I am trying to filter out something from two streams I'm trying to combine. Both values that I am trying to are of the same type so I can't seem to understand why I am getting this issue.

```
 let currentUserEmail = Observable.just(currentUserEmail)
            .unwrap()
```

//Using some internal way to get access to the email

```
let listOfAllUsers = Observable.combineLatest(getUsersList(), currentUserEmail) { allUsers, currentUserEmailAddress in
        return allUsers.filter { $0.emailAddress != currentUserEmailAddress } }
    .asObservable()
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)
```

Comment: Could you specify what your issue is exactly, because the code you posted would compiles perfectly well, assuming `getUserList` returns something like `Observable<[User]>` and `User` being something like `struct User { let emailAddress }`.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@escaping (_) -> _)' and what I don't understand is that I'm comparing both of the same types

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you in detail, if you postet all the code necessary to compile your example, so we're not something hidden in details. E.g. what exactly does `getUsersList()` return and how does your `User` structure look like?

Comment: This code actually runs but I'm not sure why it wasn't working for me but for some reason it worked when I did it as what I had below. Also the getUserList(), would have been a lot of code to attach, it was a reference to the network request.

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentUserEmail = currentUserEmail

let listOfAllUsers = getUsersList()
       .asObservable()
       .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)

let newListOfAllUsersWithoutCurrentUser = listOfAllUsers.map { allUsers in
             allUsers.filter { $0.emailAddress != currentUserEmail }
         }
         .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)
```

This worked for me in the end.